How to recover Bitlocker protected drive? Laptop fixed, now it won't allow access to NVMe drive that has Bitlocker
My wife's laptop has a slow "regular" HDD. I bought an NVMe drive and transfered the system to it, then unplugged the old drive. My wife used that setup for 3 years. 2 weeks ago our 12 year old knocked over a large cup of water into the laptop. I opened the laptop and dried it but it would not boot.
Thankfully, I had a SquareTrade protection plan. I took out the NVMe drive (since that was not original equipment) and sent the laptop in. They fixed it and I received it back today.
I installed the NVMe drive and unplugged the "regular" HDD. It came up and said "no os/boot partition found". I plugged the old HDD back in and it booted fine. Drive Management "see" the drive but it says the partition is encrypted by Bitlocker.
Thankfully I saved the BitLocker to my Microsoft account so I have access to it but I can't find anything where I can input the BitLocker key to unlock the drive so I can use it as the boot again without formatting it and losing what was on there. Much of it was saved to OneDrive but there are a few things I would really like to retrieve. She has Windows 11 Home edition.
Thanks in advance!

Right click on partition

